# Bike Accelerometer not very quick in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using the following codes for the movement of my bike.
Its working fine,but its not very quick,
It responds with the same speed,no matter how fast or how jerky I tilt my phone,
Please help me if I have to add something to the code or need to change the code.
Note : my bike runs on x axis and goes left and right on z axis.

```
float yForce = 200;
float direction = Input.acceleration.x * xForce  ;
rigidbody.AddForce(new Vector3(yForce,0,-direction));
```

And also let me know what should be the proprties of the rigidbody like drag,angular drag ,mass etc

Comment: You should first look at some [Unity tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules). Your question about the rigidbody properties make it clear you have not gone over documentation for it, and have a limited understanding of how the physics engine works, which is something your goal will require a proper understanding of.

Comment: There's also a tutorial on [accelerometer input](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/platform-specific/accelerometer-input) that you should look at.

Comment: Thank @ Assorted Trail mix, this is really gonna help me.I had gone through the documentation but as you are saying ,I think I should go once again and should read it in details.

Comment: I'm sorry, I omitted the exact part of the documentation I was referring to. Having something working means you've probably read the docs (or are super patient), I actually meant the specific *scripting* docs for the [Rigidbody](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html) class. You probably noticed the Unity docs have a habit of splitting documentation the Editor access to classes from programmatic access, and the latter is what will help here.